# Swift trigger a selector to a view from another view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a bottom view and a top view. The top view has a transparency. When the top view is dismissed I want to trigger a `#selector`. I'm not able to use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` because the bottom view is still visible. How can I trigger a `#selector` in the bottom view? Something that would replace the `viewWillAppear`?

There is a blur view behind the mainview. Im using `self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext` to present the view.

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you have an image depicting your layout.

Comment: @toddg image was added

Comment: So the top view has no reference to the bottom view? Your best bet may be a protocol-delegate approach

Comment: @toddg thats a good idea I test it out.

Comment: Checkout my Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol is best solution for you.
First you need to create protocol like this way

```
// MARK: - TopViewController Protocol
protocol TopViewControllerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func topViewWillDismissWith(data: Dictionary<String,String>)
}
```

In your `TopViewController` make property of `TopViewControllerDelegate` and when your `TopViewController` dismiss at that time you need to call delegate method like in `didTapOnDismissTopView`

```
class TopViewController : UIViewController {
   weak var delegate : TopViewControllerDelegate!
    // so on...

    // MARK: - Action method
       func didTapOnDismissTopView() {
       var dict = [String : String]()
       dict["Amount"] = "$20.00"
       dict["ExpireIn"] = "20day"
       dict["Location"] = "USA"
       dict["message"] = "hello friend this is your Answer"
       self.delegate.topViewWillDismissWith(data: dict) //Must write this line
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Now it's time to implement `TopViewControllerDelegate` protocol in `BottomViewController` it looks like

```
class BottomViewController : UIViewController,TopViewControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: - Action method

    func didTapOnDisplayTopView() {
        let topVC = TopViewController()
        topVC.delegate = self
        self.present(topVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    // MARK: - TopViewControllerDelegate
    // This method will call while topViewControllr Will Dismiss. 
    // if you want to pass data then pass otherwise you can remove perameter from method.
    func topViewWillDismissWith(data: Dictionary<String, String>) {
        // Do here which you want
    }
}
```

When you present `TopViewController` at that time you need to assign `delegate` property.when your `topViewControllr` will dismiss at that time `topViewWillDismissWith` this method will call.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: I think there might be error in your code for the bottom viewController. the `topViewWillDismiss` does not get called. the delegate was added to the class, and also to `self`. When the top view exit the data do not get passed.

Comment: Have you write this line 
self.delegate.topViewWillDismissWith(data: dict) //Must write this line
when topviewDismiss?

Comment: I was calling the wrong selector when setting the delegate. it does work perfect now thank you for the help friend

Comment: glad to help you dear friend.